# Hiredis on Windows XP SP3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this error while installing gem [hiredis](https://github.com/antirez/hiredis) on Windows XP SP3:

---

> C:\>gem install hiredis
>
> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing hiredis:
>    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
> ```
>
> System cannot find that path // <- thats just translate
>
> creating Makefile
>
> make
>
> gcc -I. -I/C/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I/C/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I.   -g -O2 -DFD_SETSIZE=256   -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hiredis-0.3.2/vendor/hiredis  -c connection.c
>   connection.c:1:24: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>
> make: ** [connection.o] Error 1

---

So I don't have file socket.h but I thought that those files are not included in win gcc dist. As you can see, RailsInstaller is used.

Answer (score 3):

Hiredis is not compatible with Windows.

See [Error when bundle install on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234493/error-when-bundle-install-on-windows/8235541#8235541)

Hiredis uses *nix sockets directly instead of a more cross-platform method like many other gems.